# IE - will not submit?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, submit

I have a fancybox where you submit a zip code in order to get channels in your area.  This seems to work in all browsers but IE, can't seem to find what is causing it to get hung up in IE, any suggestions??

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('document').ready(
    function()
    {
        //'http://fuseapi.viewerlink.tv/getProviders.asp?zip_code=' + $('#zip_look_up').val(), 
        $('#submit_zip').click(
            function(){
                $('#loading-indicator').show();
                $.get(
                    '/sites/all/modules/channelfinder/channelfinder.php?zipcode=' + $('#zip_look_up').val(),
                    function(data) 
                    {
                        $('#info_response').html('<div id="popup_questionContainer" style="padding:5px; width:auto;" class="clearfix">' +
                                        '<div style="width: auto;">' +
                                        '<div id="popup_dropDown"><select id="cableProv" name="cableProv">' +
                                        '</select></div></div>' +
                                        '<div id="popup_channelBox" style="display: none;"><span class="chanHdrBox">Fuse Channel</span>' +
                                            '<div id="popup_channelResponse"></div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '<div id="popup_hdChannelBox" style="display: none; margin-left:10px;"><span class="chanHdrBox">HD Channel</span>' +
                                            '<div id="popup_hdChannelResponse"></div>' + 
                                        '</div>' + 
                                        '</div></div>');

                                        var select = $('#cableProv');
                                        select.append("<option>Select your Service Provider</option>");
                                        $(data).find('PROVIDER').each(function()
                                        {
                                            var title = $(this).find('NAME').text();
                                            var channel = ($(this).find('HDCHANNEL').text() != '')? $(this).find('CHANNEL').text() + "," + $(this).find('HDCHANNEL').text(): $(this).find('CHANNEL').text()
                                            select.append("<option value='" + channel + "'>"+title+"</option>");
                                        });
                                        select.append("<option value='339,1339'>DIRECTV</option>");

                                        $('#cableProv').change(
                                            function()
                                            {
                                                if($('#cableProv').attr("selectedIndex") != 0)
                                                {
                                                    //console.log($('#cableProv').val().split(","));

                                                    var channelNumber = $('#cableProv').val().split(",")[0];
                                                    var hdChannelNumber = $('#cableProv').val().split(",")[1] === undefined ? 'N/A' : $('#cableProv').val().split(",")[1];

                                                    $('#popup_channelBox').show();
                                                    hdChannelNumber == 'N/A' ? $('#popup_hdChannelBox').hide() : $('#popup_hdChannelBox').show();

                                                    if (channelNumber == '') {
                                                        channelNumber = 'N/A';
                                                    }

                                                    $('#popup_channelResponse').html('<h2>'+channelNumber+'</h2>');
                                                        $('#popup_hdChannelResponse').html('<h2>'+hdChannelNumber+'</h2>');

                                                    if (channelNumber == 'N/A') {
                                                        if (hdChannelNumber != 'N/A') {
                                                            channelNumber = hdChannelNumber;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else 
                                                {
                                                }
                                            });
                        //console.log(data);
                        $('#loading-indicator').hide();
                    }); 
                });
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with IE Developer Tools? F12 will bring them up.

Comment: Do you have the issue on all versions of IE (6/7/8) or only 6/7 ?

Comment: I'm testing on IE8 and it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that jumps out at first glance is a missing semicolon on the line that begins:

```
var channel = ($(this).find( ...
```

Perhaps a subtle automatic semicolon insertion behavior is confusing IE.

Comment: @Xtian: Every line should have a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

`$('document').ready` should be `$(document).ready` or shorter `$(function() {`